# How to debug HDMI port

Tags: laptop, hdmi, firmware

I have a unique situation with a Sony Vaio that has a donor motherboard from an essentially identical Chinese model of the same. the HDMI port seems at all levels to be non-functional and not recognised, not causing any crashes or issues, just absent in all ways other than being physically present. The only sign of life I can see is that when a device is plugged into it and searching for signal, it seems to spend extra time at the port trying to communicate with it before moving on. That seems to indicate it is electrically still connected, bot there are no other signs. How can I debug the problem?

I have a [similar question](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2237618/sony-vaio-motherboard-hdmi.html#xtor=EPR-8809) on the Tom's Hardware site.

Comment: I have one really crappy tv, it also does not work with Some HDMI signals at all, when the other HDMI connecting items do. Wonder if it could be a combination of slightly off spec, low signal , slightly off termination , or some such combination of barely operational technologies :-)  Did you try a different HDMI device?

Comment: Unfortunately I only have one device to test it with... It's an interesting point about the signal strength, the projector does seem to make an effort to communicate but gives up after a while.